# Avoiding use of 'raw' in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Right now, I am using the helper method *raw* to output content from a helper method

Here's my view:

```
%ul.unstyled.barges.sortable.connectedSortable.ui-widget-content
  = raw show_list(list, columns)
```

And here's my helper:

```
def show_list(list, columns)
  content = ""
    0.upto(columns) do |c|
      content << render(:partial => 'barges/barge', :locals => {:barge => list.select{|barge| barge.location_column == c}.first})
    end
  content
end
```

Is there a way to eliminate the necessity to use raw? If I don't use *raw*, then the html will be returned as a string to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure the content is always going to be safe to output as HTML (i.e. no user input), you can return `content` as `html_safe` from your helper:

```
def show_list(list, columns)
  content = ""
    0.upto(columns) do |c|
      content << render(:partial => 'barges/barge', :locals => {:barge => list.select{|barge| barge.location_column == c}.first})
    end
  content.html_safe
end
```